# SqlAlchemy: Applying a split in filter()

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

1. I have a Checkout table where I stored "cart items" in a "cartIds" column, and the value is separated by comma. Ex) checkout.cartId <56, 54>
2. To use this data on Python I need to split it first, and make it an array to apply it in the filter, which doesn't work as I expected. See the following for the better understanding.

```
db.query(checkout, cart).filter(checkout.userId == userId, cart.id.in_(checkout.CartId.split(','))).all()
```

3. I solved it by using 'contains' in the filter, but if the database gets large, I am sure it will cause an error as it catches multiple values ex) '64' will catch 640, 641, 642.. so on.

Is there any way to get the data as I want? I've looked up several articles, but couldn't find an answer. Basically I want to retrieve the data as follows:

```
checkout = {

  "id" : 1,
   ....
   "carts": [
      {'id': 1, 'price': 12, 'title': 'iPad'},
      {'id': 2, 'price': 11, 'title': 'iPhone'}
   ]


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question, a quick comment. If you ever need to have multiple ID items in a field, it probably means you haven't completely thought out your DB design. What you're describing is a MANY-TO-MANY relationship, where a cart contains many items and each item can be contained by multiple carts (e.g. different customers can put the same item in their cart)

In that case, you'll want a connection table in between the two tables that contains the ID of the cart and the ID of an item, one one row per combination. This is explained in many different blog posts and videos, like [this one](https://www.michaelcho.me/article/many-to-many-relationships-in-sqlalchemy-models-flask).

The benefits of this approach are that you can enforce that the cart item ID exists through foreign key constraints, that you can index this relationship, meaning that MySQL doesn't have to check the entire table for matches, but can search only in a subset, and that checking a number is much faster than checking and splitting a string.

Suppose, however, that you'd still want to do this, then I would recommend you use a combination of [regex matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) and [string concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp):

```py
# Let the regex pattern be built dynamically by the query
# Look for the cartId and let it be either at the start of the string,
# or directly follow a comma, and let it be at the end of the string
# or be followed by a comma
cart_id_match_regex = func.concat('(^|,)', cart.id, '(,$)')

db.query(checkout, cart).filter(
    checkout.userId == userId,
    func.regexp_like(checkout.CartId, cart_id_match_regex)
).all()
```